# Memory leak of ssl::context using Boost::Beast

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, boost-beast

I'm attempting to solve a memory leak in [my application](https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software) that appears to only occur when I close the application.

I've installed [Deleaker](https://www.deleaker.com/), and it's pointed me to a function I adapted from a Boost/Beast example:

Deleaker message:

```
SysLat.exe!upload_data_secure Line 121 + 0x5 bytes 00df70c1 D:\Users\Skewb\Documents\repos\SysLat_Software\HTTP_Client_Async_SSL.h, line 121
```

Code:

```
inline http::response<http::string_body> upload_data_secure(Json::Value dataToSend, char const* target = "/api/benchmarkData") {

    char const* host = "syslat.com";
    char const* port = "443";

    int version = 11;

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ ssl::context::tlsv13_client }; //MEMORY LEAK APPEARS TO OCCUR HERE

    //beast::error_code ec2;
    // This holds the root certificate used for verification
    load_root_certificates(ctx);

    // Verify the remote server's certificate
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);

    auto sharedPointer = std::make_shared<SSL_session>(net::make_strand(ioc),ctx);
    auto prv = sharedPointer->run(dataToSend, host, port, target, version);

    ioc.run();

    http::response<http::string_body> rv = *prv;

    return rv;
}
```

[Here's the file (and line) in question.](https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/12ba3902535a79bf4abd359b8c699519524d5e4b/HTTP_Client_Async_SSL.h#L121)

- Do I need to be doing something to delete that object?
- Is the way I'm using `<SSL_session>` in a `shared_ptr` causing the issue?

Comment: You might get better attention of those familiar when fully qualifying with what you have questions (like I understand it is "boost::asio::ssl::context").

Comment: probably just some static allocation somewhere in beast/asio/openssl, its only 5 bytes allocated once, don't worry about it

Comment: @ÖöTiib, sorry I'm not even sure how to further qualify the question. I ask at the bottom "Is the way I'm using ```ctx``` in a ```shared_ptr``` causing the issue"... are you saying I should move that up and/or move that into the question?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I guess that will likely be what I'm going to do. To clarify, I'm doing this not only to optimize my program, but also as an exercise for myself. Is it fairly standard for static allocation to cause memory leaks when an application is closed? Maybe just as a Windows issue?

Comment: @Skewjo The name "ctx" was apparently given by yourself to variable of type boost::asio::ssl::context. So you are apparently asking about your usage of boost::asio::ssl::context not "ctx".

Comment: Its common for memory leak detectors to flag up statically allocated objects. They aren't memory leaks though and the memory should be freed when your code is unloaded. when looking for memory leaks look for repeated allocations, single allocations especially when small you can ignore